# structr is it right to use

Tags: java, neo4j, structr

I am going to develop my application in neo4j ,i found structr which is something based on neo4j.

What is structr?

Is it something like spring or hibernate  or something totally different,what kind of problems it can solve and is it stable enough to be used in production.

Comment: Consider visiting the main website (https://structr.org/) for information about what the project is.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I'm the founder of the project)

Structr can be used as

- Rapid Application Development Tool
- Content Management System
- JSON Document Database
- Graph Editing/Visualization Tool

It's an end-user facing product with UI, not a library or mapping layer, although it sports a Java-based OGM (Object Graph Mapper).

It is stable and used in production.